# Too many parameters trying to rebuild VGG16

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

So i was trying to do some transfer learning in keras using the VGG16 architecture and imagenet weights. I wanted the last couple of layers to be trained on random weights and biases so I used `model.pop()` to get rid of them and added the last couple of layers manually. When calling `model.summary()` it looks exactly the same except the number of parameters in the last block of convolutional layers (the ones that I added) went from about 2.3 million to 51 million. I am not sure what is causing this huge increase in parameters? Can someone explain this to me? It is causing my computer to run out of resources when (I'm assuming ram since I only have 16 gb). The following is the code that I used to build the model.

```
def build_model():
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=True)
model.input
model.summary()
for l in model.layers:
    l.trainable =False
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()
model.layers.pop()


orig = model.input


new_model = Conv2D(512,(14,14),activation='relu',padding='same',name='conv1')(model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)
new_model = Conv2D(512,(14,14),activation='relu',padding='same',name='conv2')(new_model)
new_model =Conv2D(512,(14,14),activation='relu',padding='same',name='conv3')(new_model)
new_model =MaxPooling2D((2,2),name='pool')(new_model)
new_model =Flatten(name='flatten')(new_model)
new_model =Dense(4096,activation='relu',name='fc1')(new_model)
new_model =Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='fc2')(new_model)
new_model =Dense(512,activation='relu',name='fc3')(new_model)
new_model =Dense(2,activation='softmax',name='output')(new_model)
model = Model(orig,new_model)
model.summary()

return model
```

I was in a rush and forgot to put the output of `model.summary()`.
This is the summary for the original VGG16:

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 1000)              4097000   
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

This is the output for the modified network:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 512)       51380736  
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 512)       51380736  
_________________________________________________________________
conv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 512)       51380736  
_________________________________________________________________
pool (MaxPooling2D)          (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 1024)              4195328   
_________________________________________________________________
fc3 (Dense)                  (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 1026      
=================================================================
Total params: 269,263,170
Trainable params: 261,627,906
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: model.summary() will tell you exactly how many parameters each layer has, that is the answer to your question.

Comment: I just added the output for model.summary(). I am not sure what caused the increase in Conv2D parameters from the VGG16 model to the last 3 Conv2D layers (the ones that I added with Keras). The summary looks the same except for the number of parameters.

Comment: VGG uses 3x3 filters, while your filters are 14x14.

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much